# Mac always restarting after reboot

Tags: macos, applescript, reboot, calendar.app

I created an AppleScript to restart my Mac:

```
tell application "System Events"
restart
end tell
```

I put this script into Calendar.app and set it to start at 7.00. When I put script into calendar and click done button it will restart my OS  over and over again. It's like the Mac is restoring the system to the pre-shutdown state, including re-launching any applications that were open at the time.

How can I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting up in single user mode by holding command-S on startup, running `mount -uw /` (`fsck -fy` is probably not needed), and removing these files:

```
rm /Users/username/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.loginwindow.*.plist
rm -r /Users/yourusername/Library/Saved\ Application\ State
```

Comment: Hi ,I don t know how exacly I can remove these files? Could you be more specific like? Should I type it in terminal or .... ? thx for any replie

Answer (score 0):

@Macko

Like @Lri said

#### Step 1) Start up in single user mode

**Hold down Command-S** when your computer is starting up.
You will be presented with a command line.

#### Step 2) Type in these 2 lines

```
rm /Users/username/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.loginwindow.*.plist
```

*press enter*

```
rm -r /Users/yourusername/Library/Saved\ Application\ State
```

Hopefully, this should stop your computer from restarting.

#### Fixing your code is an entirely different issue

At one point, I had my mac laptop re-starting on a schedule (a few operating systems back, on OSX Snow Leopard), but there should be an easier way.

[This article](http://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=6553) is written for Snow Leopard, but the preferences are still in the same location on Mavericks.

Feel free to comment with other questions!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still an issue, just realized it was posted 10 months ago. Oh well!